# MouseEnter and MouseLeave on an Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've seen this question before, but none of the solutions I've seen hence far have worked.

I'm attempting to simply get the image to fade in when hovered over and fade out when not. The following is a snippet of my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#jenn">
      <img class="img-fade" src="img/team/jenn.jpg" alt="Jenn">Jenn
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have some CSS that sets .img-fade to opacity: 0.5;.

Then my tabs.js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.img-fade').mouseenter(function() {
      $('.img-fade').fadeTo('fast',1);
   });
   $('.img-fade').mouseleave(function() {
      $('.img-fade').fadeTo('fast',0.5);
   });
});
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working. It seems simplistic enough. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you setup a demo on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/NK3Tu/

Comment: Can't you just use a CSS3 transition for that?

P.S.: seems to be working here on your jsfiddle. (Google Chrome 28.x)

Comment: Are you importing your jquery correctly? I have done an example with the same code - except the image source - and it works. You can also do this with css hover.

Comment: @SiddharthaGupta's demonstration seems to work perfectly. Are you sure you are including the `tabs.js` source in your main file?

Comment: yours is already working [http://jsfiddle.net/gr6nQ/](http://jsfiddle.net/gr6nQ/) which browser are you tesing it in?

Comment: @Floris yeah I'm positive I'm including it perfectly. Really not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: @rps I'm testing it in Chrome

Comment: What means not working??? Get any error in console??? Why not use $(this) inside handlers?

Comment: @MitulP91 does the event fire? Seems like it must be a syntax error given that the JSFiddle is working. Check for class name typos perhaps?

Comment: ok- longshot. Change your class name from img-fade to imgfade and see if that helps.

Comment: is the JS file loaded correctly? your code is fine but It is not getting fired it seems and yes include jquery files as per the answer suggested below

Comment: I feel like there may be some interference from other JS files that I have included. Gonna comb through them and see if I can find an issue. Thanks for the help guys. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with the following reference to jquery in the header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

And it worked well! Are you still having issues?

Comment: Yeah still can't seem to get it working. Everything looks correct to me.

Comment: Ah made a stupid spelling mistake when including these. Ha! Thanks for the help Stephanie.